# How do run some code when an UIView is loaded on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, code-injection

I want to run some code when **any** UIView is loaded from the resources.

How can I do that, without having to modify implementation of each UIView subclass?

Note: subclassing UIView is not an option.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass UIView and then use your subclass for all your others UIviews

Answer (score 1):

You could consider creating a `UIView`, which will be the base view class to all your `UIView` as suggested by **@gsempe** and implement the `willMoveToSuperview:` method.

From Documentation.

> Tells the view that its superview is
>   about to change to the specified
>   superview.

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview;
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking resources and NIB implicitly, I can recollect only two methods in which you would load a view – `UIViewController`'s `initWithNibName:bundle` or `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` although there might be some private methods that we aren't provided access to.

So you can think of overriding behavior there. You can create a custom `UIViewController` subclass that will be the parent for all your view controller's and subclass `NSBundle` to override `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`. But this might depend on what kind of task you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring your own category and override a method, but I don't think that would be a good practice. Other way is to extend the UIView subclass and override the method you want. And use that class in your application instead of UIView.

So the approach really depends on your use case.